# How to change an origin/main branch to a previous commit?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have the following repository:

[image: Screenshot of Git commits from the Git Graph extension in VS Code, showing origin/main at the latest commit and main & origin/master at the ancestor commit.]

How to "undo" this revert and leave the "main" as the repository leaf?

Comment: To "undo" a revert, revert it. I do not know what you think "leave the main as the repository leaf" means.

Comment: If you wish you had never added the revert commit, you could reset --hard back one step. But I don't advise that, on main.

Comment: Is "repository leaf" a term you just made up? If so, then how to you expect anyone to understand what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

`main` is already where you want `origin/main` to be, so push main. It’ll need to be a force push because you’re dropping the revert commit.

```
git push --force origin main:main
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to maintain a clean git history. This assumes you haven't committed anything further.

```bash
git revert HEAD
git push origin
```

If you want to completely remove the prior commit and lose the history you can

```bash
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push origin
```